# how to get the standard and custom fields present in a pagelayout

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image]I am having two dependent  picklist.when i select case object in first picklist it has to show the fields present in pagelayout instead of displaying all the fields in object.

Comment: your question is not clear, given some example or screen print

Comment: i am using describe method to display all the fields from the case object.Insetad of displaying all the fields present in case object is there any other way to display the fields present in the case page layout

Comment: You can refer the below post. [Get fields from Page layout](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/240726/is-there-a-way-to-query-exclusively-the-fields-in-the-page-layout-for-an-sobject)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, you want display specific fields which are available on the page layout and not all the fields.

If that is correct then better to go for `fieldSets`

Refer [Working with Field Sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm)

You can use dynamic bindings to display field sets on your Visualforce pages. A field set is a grouping of fields. For example, you could have a field set that contains fields describing a user's first name, middle name, last name, and business title. If the page is added to a managed package, administrators can add, remove, or reorder fields in a field set to modify the fields presented on the Visualforce page without modifying any code

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Contact.FieldSets.properNames}" var="f"> 
        <apex:outputText value="{!Contact[f]}" /><br/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be field accessibility problem. Check whether you have access to all fields otherwise the class which you are using should be public class className instead of public with sharing class.